# Подсветка для активной категории

Tags: php

Добрый день! Имеется запрос, который реализует вывод категорий из БД одной таблицы. Кто знает, как можно выделить ту категорию, на которой находится посетитель? Подскажите пожалуйста) Вот запрос php:

```
<?                
           $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,adres FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5",$db);

            if (!$result3)
            {
            echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору afonya94@bk.ru <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
            exit(mysql_error());
            }               
            if (mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0)                
            {
            $myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

            do 
            {
            printf ("<p class='categ2'><img src='images/novosti.png' style='margin: 0 8px 2px 0;'><a class='nav_link2' href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></p>",$myrow3["adres"],$myrow3["title"]);               
            }
            while ($myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3));                                 
            }               
            else
            {
            echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена в таблице нет записей.</p>";
            exit();
            }                             
           ?>
```

Comment: @DimasikYES, во-первых, я вам уже советовал, чтоб вы напрочь забыли, как страшный сон, обо всех уроках Попова и о самом Попове в принципе. Во-вторых, есть много способов подсвечивать активный пункт меню и выбирать какой-либо из них, надо исходя из определенных условий, которые присутствуют в проекте. Как минимум, нужно знать в каком виде у вас генерируются ссылки и какие параметры передаются при GET-запросах.

Comment: Ну посоветуйте тогда уроки других авторов!

Comment: "в каком виде у вас генерируются ссылки и какие параметры передаются при GET-запросах" все также, как у Попова.

Comment: @DimasikYES, начнем с того, что я как и подавляющее большинство порядочных веб-разработчиков, Попова за автора не считают. Это проходимец, который "учит" новичков чистейшему *овнокоду, еще и деньги на этом зарабатывает. По поводу того, что читать - уже не раз обсуждалось на форуме. Смотрите через поиск. Но моё мнение, что для начала, не плохо бы познакомится с сайтами [php.net][1], [php.su][2] и т.д.

   [1]: http://php.net/
   [2]: http://www.php.su/